# Convert a JSON into a UTF-8 string

Tags: php, string, json

I want to convert a JSON object into a string. when I am using `json_encode` I get a string but all with hex letters. I want to convert it to a UTF-8. In other words I want to see the characters.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 7):

I was using `json_encode` to store data such as Arabic Characters in MySQL fields.

It would store the Arabic characters as HEX within the Database like this:

> u0644 u063a...

Which is incorrect. You must ensure that you wrap your `json_encode` with `mysql_escape_string()`.

This will make sure that the data is put in MySQL as:

> \u0644\u063a...

Then, when you use `json_decode`, it converts the HEX strings into UTF-8 and is output correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can try passing an option to `json_encode()`:

```
json_encode ( $value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

The `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option is only available in PHP version 5.4.0 and later.

Thanks.

Comment: i am using this function as i mention above but the characters are in Hex and not in UTF-8

Comment: Which options should the OP use to get the output he wants?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, [in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659140/is-phps-json-encode-guaranteed-to-produce-ascii-string/2659228#2659228). Besides, the strings will still be the same once you decode them.

Comment: yes i know that but i want to show the characters on screen for user

Answer (score 1):

you are looking exactly for the funcition `json_decode`
it can convert json strings into utf8

here is an example of arabic word

```
$re = json_encode('لغة عربية'); 
echo $re ; 
$dd = json_decode($re);
echo $dd ; 
die;
```

it output  :
`"\u0644\u063a\u0629 \u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629"`
  `لغة عربية`

more examples here 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: could you please make  sure that your json data is valid , check json.org , or share it with us