# JSON Decode to UTF-8

Tags: php, json

I want to decode json output to utf-8.

```
$sql = "select * from nganhang";
$kq = mysql_query($sql);

$posts = array();
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($kq)) 
    {
            $posts[] = array('node_list_bank'=>array_map('utf8_encode',$post));
        }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('list_bank'=>$posts));
```

This Output

```
{"list_bank":[{"node_list_bank":{"manganhang":"acb","tennganhang":"Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng \u00c3\u0081 Ch\u00c3\u00a2u ACB"}},{"node_list_bank":{"manganhang":"agb","tennganhang":"Agribank - Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng n\u00c3\u00b4ng nghi\u00e1\u00bb\u0087p v\u00c3\u00a0 ph\u00c3\u00a1t tri\u00e1\u00bb\u0083n n\u00c3\u00b4ng th\u00c3\u00b4n Vi\u00e1\u00bb\u0087t Nam"}},{"node_list_bank":{"manganhang":"mhb","tennganhang":"Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng ph\u00c3\u00a1t tri\u00e1\u00bb\u0083n nh\u00c3\u00a0 \u00c4\u0091\u00e1\u00bb\u0093ng b\u00e1\u00ba\u00b1ng s\u00c3\u00b4ng C\u00e1\u00bb\u00adu Long"}},{"node_list_bank":{"manganhang":"bidv","tennganhang":"Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng \u00c4\u0090\u00e1\u00ba\u00a7u t\u00c6\u00b0 v\u00c3\u00a0 Ph\u00c3\u00a1t tri\u00e1\u00bb\u0083n Vi\u00e1\u00bb\u0087t Nam"}},{"node_list_bank":{"manganhang":"vdb","tennganhang":"Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng Ph\u00c3\u00a1t tri\u00e1\u00bb\u0083n Vi\u00e1\u00bb\u0087t Nam"}},{"node_list_bank":{"manganhang":"vbsp","tennganhang":"Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng Ch\u00c3\u00adnh s\u00c3\u00a1ch X\u00c3\u00a3 h\u00e1\u00bb\u0099i Vi\u00e1\u00bb\u0087t Nam"}}]}
```

I want ouput result format uft-8 ... How to do :(

```
$encode = json_encode(array('list_bank'=>$posts));
$decode = json_decode($encode,true);
echo $decode;
```

Sorry i use english not good :(

Comment: Well, what are you currently getting? Also, the data needs to be `json_encode`d in UTF-8 to begin with.

Comment: "Ng\u00c3\u00a2n h\u00c3\u00a0ng Ph\u00c3\u00a1t tri\u00e1\u00bb\u0083n Vi\u00e1\u00bb\u0087t Nam ... this output ... I want outout this "Ngân hàng Phát triển Việt Nam"

Comment: post the array result of `list_bank'=>$posts`

Comment: http://qhoang.org/webservices/get_list_bank.php <-- this result

Comment: that's the json_encoded one, can we see the array?

Comment: sorry i was edited my question

Comment: `array('list_bank'=>$posts)` can you display the output of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a JSON into a UTF-8 string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409039/convert-a-json-into-a-utf-8-string)

Comment: echo array('list_bank'=>$posts); --> output is "Array" .. i don't  get anymore :(

Comment: @deceze i don't understand your comment

Comment: @deceze this output "NgÃƒÂ¢n hÃƒÂ ng ÃƒÂ ChÃƒÂ¢u ACB"

Comment: That could be anything, but I'll guess that you're not pulling your data from the database in UTF-8.

Comment: this link i insert data to database http://qhoang.org/webservices/add_item.php?p=addBANK ..:(

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to send the right headers.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$encode = json_encode(array('list_bank'=>$posts));
$decode = json_decode($encode, true);
print_r($decode);
```

Also, you can't `echo` an array, you must use `print_r`.

Answer (score 0):

Include the next header at the beginning of the .php file

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
...
```

and add 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in your json_encode

```
echo json_encode(array('list_bank'=>$posts), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Be sure to remove the utf8_encode() and json_decode() they are unnecessary.