# JSON object as php string

Tags: php, string, json, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a JSON into a UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409039/convert-a-json-into-a-utf-8-string)

I am working on caching some twitter feeds for long term use. The result of my search yields the following type of data structure:

```
"results": [
{
  "created_at": "Sun, 08 Apr 2012 18:31:04 +0000",
  "entities": {
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "text": "cheeringfor",
        "indices": [
          54,
          66
        ]
      }
    ],
    "urls": [

    ],
    "user_mentions": [
      {
        "screen_name": "BenSpies11",
        "name": "Ben Spies",
        "id": 32124771,
        "id_str": "32124771",
        "indices": [
          0,
          11
        ]
      }
    ]
  },...
```

I am trying to include the hashtags section of this output in my database table but I am trying to save it as plain string.

I have tried casting it as a string i:e `(string)$result->hashtags` but I get the **cannot be converted to string** error. I also tried the **serialize()** function which worked but got php errors when I tried to un-serialize and get my object back.

Comment: Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409039/convert-a-json-into-a-utf-8-string. This post should be closed

Comment: No, cause that is another question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, look up php's json_decode function. It will transform your JSON string to a data structure, and then you should be able to look up your hashtags like:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonstring, true);
$hashtags = $data['results'][0]['entities']['hashtags']; // this will be an array
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that is correct. In case it's not exactly right, you can read about json_decode() here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: you forgot the 2 param? json_decode($jsonstring,true);

Answer (score 1):

According with your syntax, for print hashtag string you should write:

```
$result = json_decode($your_json);
echo $result->results[0]->entities->hashtags[0]->text;
```