# How do I save utf-8 encoded json with PHP to a .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, encoding

I am trying to save some data on the server but finding some encoding problems.

This is how I am sending my objects to PHP (which works fine but I don't think the contentType is actually doing anything):

```
$.post(
  'myfile.php',
   {
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
       data : myData
   },
   function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      //some code here
   }
);
```

and then in PHP (myfile.php):

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

   $file = 'data/theData.txt'; //the file to edit
   $current = file_get_contents($file); // Open the file to get existing content
   $a2 = json_decode( $current, true );

   $data = $_POST['data']; //the data from the webpage

   $res = array_merge_recursive( $data, $a2 );

   $resJson = json_encode( $res );

   // Write the contents back to the file
   file_put_contents($file, $resJson);
?>
```

As you can see I am getting the original contents of the file and decoding the json. I am then merging the result with the data sent from the webpage before re-encoding in json and put the contents back.

This all works as expected. However, at one point in my Jquery the data sent contains a wide variety of symbols like "/ ö é ł Ż ę"

When the file is saved each '/' has an escape character '\' in front of it and likewise the 'é' for example is '\u00e9'

How do I override this? Should I try to convert it properly in the PHP or is their a way in the JQuery to convert back to the correct format after I have $.get('data/theData.txt'?

Any light shed on this issue is greatly appreciated! Please excuse the poor variable names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a JSON into a UTF-8 string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409039/convert-a-json-into-a-utf-8-string)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I don't think that's a dup.

Comment: use base64_encode() on the $_POST value and give it to us. This preserves the string binary safe for us, so we can tell you if its utf8 or not.

Comment: @Alix: Asker wants their JSON encoded as UTF-8, not ASCII with Unicode escapes. PHP doesn't do that.

Comment: @chris Sorry, my PHP is very rusty. The $_POST['data'] value is an array so how should I base64 encode it?

Comment: `echo base64_encode($_POST['data']);` and give it to us.

Comment: I couldn't work out how to get echo to work because as soon as the script has run, it goes to a new page (I am using JQuery Mobile). I tried this but think its wrong. All I had was an empty text file

$data = base64_encode($_POST['data']);
file_put_contents($file, $data);

Comment: Hello Patrick, Chris asked you to do give him the output of the code he mentioned in his comment, not to save it into a file.

Comment: Hi @xFortyFourx I was having problems using echo in the php script. It just runs the script and after there is a JQuery line to go to a new page. So I tried to write the output to a file, but it was just blank. Am I doing something stupid!? I took away the '$.mobile.changePage( "#page_thisPage", { transition: "slidedown"} );' jquery mobile line, but still nothing was echoed.

Comment: Is the original webpage utf-8?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by @chalet16 helped but if JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE doesn't work for you this does the job!

```
$myString = $json_encode($myObject); 
//After initially encoding to json there are escapes on all '/' and characters like ö é ł Ż ę

//First unescape slashes:
$myString = str_replace("\/","/",$myString);

//Then escape double quotes
$myString = str_replace('"','\\"',$myString);

//And Finally:
$myNewString = json_decode('"'.$myString.'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP >=5.4.0, you can use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option in json_encode function. Please look at [php.net: json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for more details.

For PHP < 5.4.0, there are some comments about how to do this in user contributed notes on the same page, but it is uncertain that it will work correctly or not.

Comment: Thanks @chalet16 That helped greatly. Sadly the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option didn't work for me but the other comments fixed it.